# how to change a css of an input if the value of it is not empty in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hello everyone I would like to change the css of my input if its not empty with angularJS how can ı do that I searched for it but couldn't be successful ? 
for example 

I would like to change the css if the value has changed

thanks in advance

Comment: looks like you want http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already done a sample like as you said. Please refer [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pL9df/) for details.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testController">
    <input type="text" ng-class="cssClass" ng-change="changeCssInput()" ng-model="text"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.input-blue {
    border: 3px solid blue;
}

.input-red {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('testController', function ($scope)
{
    $scope.text = '';
    $scope.cssClass = 'input-red';    
    $scope.changeCssInput = function () {
        $scope.cssClass = $scope.text.length <= 0 ? 'input-red' : 'input-blue';  
    }
});
```

Please let me know if any missing.

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 2):

use ng-class directive to change class of input conditionally,

```
<input ng-class="{'class1' : expression1}"/>
```

this code add **class1** to input if expression result is true...